# execv() the exact same binary on Linux?

Tags: linux

I am looking for a way on Linux to fork a child process that runs exactly the same binary as its parent.

The basic mechanism that I see available is fork() and execv(). The trouble is what parameter to supply to execv() to run exactly the same code?

The nearest solution I have found is to run /proc/$$/exe. The trouble is that this is only a symlink and so if the executable had been modified on disk after my process started then the child would end up running the new version. I am looking for a more robust solution such that in practice I can depend on the parent and child processes to be running the same code even if software is being reinstalled in the background.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Is it possible to fork and just call something useful instead?

Comment: `fork()` *does* create a child that runs the same binary as the parent.

Comment: You shouldn't need to re-exec. A forked process already runs the same binary as its parent. You probably  just want to release some resources (close semaphores, O_CLOEXEC filedescriptors, etc.) and jump back to main. (by calling `exit(main(...));` from the child)

Comment: I want to start a fresh process running exactly the same software. I have too much complex state in my process to deallocate manually without the risk of errors (virtual machines, scheduler affinities, memory mappings, signal handlers, etc etc etc).

Comment: I considered reconstructing the binary as a file by consulting /proc/$self/maps to locate the relevant bytes in my process address space, but this did not seem sufficiently simple (mapped in multiple segments.)